# Spark leftOuterJoin issue - leftOuterJoin is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper for leftOuterJoin. I'm starting up like this and encountering strange issue,

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

case class Joins(self: RDD[(String,String)]) {
        def loj(other: RDD[(String,String)]) = {
        (self.leftOuterJoin(other))
      }
    }
```

> error: value leftOuterJoin is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]

**Where I'm going wrong here ?**

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is just a highlighting error, so could you add

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._
```

it seems that `SparkContext._` behavior changed for [Spark 1.4.x](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html), `SparkContext._` is not mandatory anymore, but it still required for the IDE to recognize the correct types.

Comment: I'm using spark 1.2.1 and "import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._" throws error " class RDD exists, but it has no companion object."